# omniauth-wordpress-oauth2-plugin gem install error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation

On Rails 4, in my gemfile:

gem 'omniauth-wordpress-oauth2-plugin', github: 'jwickard/omniauth-wordpress-oauth2-plugin'

Then I run bundle:

```
Fetching git://github.com/jwickard/omniauth-wordpress-oauth2-plugin.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Could not find gem 'omniauth-wordpress-oauth2-plugin (>= 0) ruby' in git://github.com/jwickard/omniauth-wordpress-oauth2-plugin.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'omniauth-wordpress-oauth2-plugin (>= 0) ruby'
```

I've tried with 1.9.3, 2.0, 2.1, using rvm

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you should add is :

```
gem 'omniauth-wordpress_hosted', github: 'jwickard/omniauth-wordpress-oauth2-plugin'
```

As the guy as changed it's gem name, without updating the documentation. Seen here : https://github.com/jwickard/omniauth-wordpress-oauth2-plugin/commit/0fce4274b3b8ffedc28332f01076d65b60c7c158#diff-89bd019d22c33b336d6c70080cc17cd7R9

I just tested, `bundle install` works with that name ;)